# Split a string into a list of tuples based selectively on specific commas within the string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a long Python string of the form:

```
string='Black<5,4>, Black<9,4>'
```

How can I split this string, and any other of arbitrary length which has the same form (i.e. `<ArbitraryString1<ArbitraryListOfIntegers1>,<ArbitraryString2<ArbitraryListOfIntegers2>,...`) into a list of tuples.

For example, the following would be the desired output from `string`:

```
list_of_tuples=[('Black',[5,4]),'Black,[9,4])
```

Usually I'd use `string.split` on the commas to produce a list and then regex to separate the word from the `<>` but since I need to use commas to delimit my indices (the contents of the `<>`), this doesn't work.

Comment: string will always come in this format?

Comment: is it not possible to use split with the `', '` (coma AND space) separator instead of only the coma for the first split?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use a regex to capture 1+ word chars before a `<` and capture everything inside `<...>` into another group, and then split Group 2 contents with `,` casting the values to int:

```
import re
s='Black<5,4>, Black<9,4>'
print([(x, map(int, y.split(','))) for x,y in re.findall(r'(\w+)<([^<>]+)>', s)])
# => [('Black', [5, 4]), ('Black', [9, 4])]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/IUXzol)

**Pattern details**:

- `(\w+)` - group 1 (assigned to `x`): 1 or more word chars
- `<` - a literal `<`
- `([^<>]+)` - Group 2 (assigned to `y`): 1+ chars other than `<` and `>`
- `>`  - a literal `>`.

Answer (score 2):

alternatively, you could do the splitting on commas not enclosed in `<,>` manually and then process the parts later:

```
string = 'Black<5,4>, Black<9,4>'

chunks = []
s = string + ','
N = len(s)
pos, level = 0, 0
for i in range(0, N):
    if s[i] == '<':
        level += 1

    elif s[i] == '>':
        level -= 1

    elif s[i] == ',':
        if level == 0:
            chunks.append(s[pos:i])
            pos = i+1

print(chunks)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split at `", "` (notice the whitespace) and then proccess the data.

**Example Code:**

```
string='Black<5,4>, Black<9,4>'

splitted_string = string.split(', ')

list_of_tuples = []
for s in splitted_string:
  d = s.replace("<", " <").split()

  color = d[0]
  n1 = d[1].replace("<", "").replace(">","").split(",")[0]
  n2 = d[1].replace("<", "").replace(">","").split(",")[1]

  t = (d[0], [n1, n2])
  list_of_tuples.append(t)

print(list_of_tuples)
```

**Output:**

```
[('Black', ['5', '4']), ('Black', ['9', '4'])]
```